# CGRect is not working in closure outside of viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, closures, cgrect

I am trying to use `CGRect` to make a rectangle shape and then later return it once this works it will allow me to set constraints on it to place it where I want, I am using it inside of this closure and it is giving me an error. This is placed outside of my `viewDidLoad`

```
let logo : UIImageView = {
let myLogo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.height*(77/812)*2.078, height:  self.view.frame.height*(77/812)))

    myLogo.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ftrLogo")
    return myLogo

}()
```

Comment: You should put it in `viewDidLoad`. Why did you not put it in `viewDidLoad` in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper I tried that already when I do that my constraint setup, placed outside of the view did load doesn't recognize the constant 'logo'

Comment: Mark `logo` as a `lazy var`.

Comment: I meant that you should keep a `var logo: UIImageView!` property outside `viewDidLoad`. In `viewDidLoad`, do `logo = { ... }()` or whatever you like with `logo`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Eilon that did not work either, using a lazy variable.

Comment: I just got rid of using it outside of the viewdid load and put everything inside of it without using constraint. Just laid everything out on my story board via cg rect x and y position @Sweeper

Answer (score 1):

You should probably make your logo a lazy var. Do like this:

```
    lazy var logo : UIImageView = {

    let myLogo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.height*(77/812)*2.078, height:  self.view.frame.height*(77/812)))

        myLogo.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ftrLogo")
        return myLogo

    }()
```